# Permit writing to directory only when SAN is mounted

Tags: linux, unix, san

The problem statement is this: I have a directory which is configured as a mountpoint for a SAN partition. Now this SAN partition gets mounted several minutes after boot due to some reasons which I cannot avoid. In the meantime, some processes start writing to the directory (which is still not on SAN and just a local directory), thereby causing trouble.

My goal is to ensure that I do not allow any process to write in the directory while it is local. As soon as SAN gets mounted on it, the processes are free to write.

Comment: Do you mean _"do not allow any process to write in the directory **while** it is local"_

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the mount point immutable:

```
# chattr +i /mnt/foo
```

Verify that you cannot write there:

```
# touch /mnt/foo/hello
touch: cannot touch ‘/srv/test/foo’: Permission denied
```

And now perform the mount:

```
# mount /dev/foo /mnt/foo
```

Comment: While "chmod +i" did not work on my system, I tried "chattr +i /mnt/foo" and it worked like a charm.

Comment: my bad, I meant to type ``chattr`` (I experimented with using both ``chmod 700`` and ``chattr +i`` and must have gotten them mixed up when typing it up)